# A theatrical Spoonerism

Tags: cryptic-crosswords

> Leak plays (illegally) to Spooner, but they may not see the stage (5,
>   5)

Adding more text to meet the quality standards. Is this enough?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The answer is

> CHEAP SEATS
>  def: they may not see the stage
>  leak plays (illegally) = seep cheats, Spoonerised to cheap seats